# How to copy data from one database table to another database table?

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb, insert-into

I need help about my coding in vb.net copying data from one database table to another database table in ms access database.

Here are my codes:

```
Dim conn2 As OleDbConnection
   Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand
   Dim SQLStr2 As String


    conn2 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=cscfo13poppsi; ")


   SQLStr2 = "SELECT * FROM pop IN '" & TextBox3.Text & "'"
   conn2.Open()
   cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(SQLStr2, conn2)
   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

   Dim conn As OleDbConnection
   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
   Dim SQLStr1 As String

   conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=psipop.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=cscfo13poppsi;")
   SQLStr1 = "INSERT INTO pop 'psipop'"
   conn.Open()
   cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQLStr1, conn)
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The error is "syntax error in INSERT INTO"

Comment: what is 'psipop' in the second part of the code?

Comment: Are you trying to copy a row or the entire table?  Having the user type in the DataSource is a really bad idea, but is TextBox3 the DS or table name?  There is plenty missing there such as something to hold the results from the first query

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of your INSERT statement is wrong. Try this:

```
Insert Into pop Values('psipop')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this matter. It works!

Just visit to this link : [Copy records from one database to another database](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?401529-Copy-records-from-one-database-to-another)